# Problem with fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, unmount

I have a linux server where i have setup a nextcloud instance. I have 2 hdd´s that i have combined to one folder to mnt/cloud.
It has been working great, but over the last week it randomly unmounts "Cloud" and i reboot and its connected again. Anyone that has any idea what is going on ?

my fstab config:

```
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
/dev/sdb1     /mnt/cloud1      ext4        defaults      0     2
/dev/sdc1     /mnt/cloud2      ext4        defaults      0     2
#mhddfs
mhddfs#/mnt/cloud1,/mnt/cloud2 /mnt/cloud fuse allow_other,nonempty 0 0
```

As it is now it can happen every 10 min, and some times its much longer.
Really wanna figure this out, but i cant find any info on this. Im quite new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: thanks, ill run that command as soon as it unmounts again.

Comment: So i got the error again. 

: mhddfs[10377]: segfault at 0 ip 000055cb700c3f2c sp 00007fe057f44a00 error 4 in mhddfs[55cb700be000+b000]

Any input on what this is ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the latest version of mhddfs, you might want to try third party solution, which works flawlessly for me.

Get the fix from this repo [vdudouyt/mhddfs-nosegfault](https://github.com/vdudouyt/mhddfs-nosegfault)

Searching this on [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mhddfs+segmentation+fault) also reveals a lot of discussions